# Filtering PowerShell Query Output

Tags: windows, powershell, script

I'm searching for a way to filter the output of a query in PowerShell on Windows 10. The output of this command

```
query user /server:$SERVER
```

is currently

```
PS C:\Users\Station> query user /server:$SERVER
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>station               console             1  Active      none   2/26/2021 10:07 AM
```

and I need to filter it into a string that I plan to use for a variable, such as

```
station
```

Note that the output does not have the greater than sign `>`. Forgive me if this is something simple that I've overlooked, but I've been searching with no luck for far too long. For the love of God, please help.

Comment: I use a PS cmd let called “Get-UserSession” and it has helped tremendously. With it I would call `Get-UserSession | Select Username`. It is part of the WFTools package at PowerShellGallery (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WFTools/0.1.37/Content/Get-UserSession.ps1). Note, it is either this or use regex/string manipulation to do the work yourself of extracting that value. This is because `query.exe` returns standard text as output and does not use objects like PowerShell does.

Comment: Also, `Get-UserSession` can be used on remote machines as well: `Get-UserSession -ComputerName $server`

Comment: Your question is not about Powershell, so, why tag it that way. You are using a Windows OS executable, that you are trying to parse, not really filter. A `filter` means to limit from a list and you seem to be saying you are trying to extract the `>station` value. What did you search for? What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, There are a number of ways to do this.

RegEx, Substring, etc...as noted by what `JG7` pointed you to.

It's just a string. So, `split`, `substring`, `match|matches`, Select-String to the string index/pattern you are looking for and strip the special character using -replace.

Native query

```
query user /server:$env:COMPUTERNAME
```

Drop the header

```
(query user /server:$env:COMPUTERNAME)[1]
```

Select the fixed filed width for username

```
(((query user /server:$env:COMPUTERNAME)[1]).TrimStart()).SubString(0,21)
```

There is a leading space, thus a special character. So, let's just dump all special characters.

```
'>' + (((query user /server:$env:COMPUTERNAME)[1]).TrimStart()).SubString(0,21)
```

If there are special characters, then replace them

```
(((query user /server:$env:COMPUTERNAME)[1]).TrimStart()).SubString(0,21) -replace '\W'
# Results
<#
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 postanote             rdp-tcp#0           2  Active          .  01-Mar-21 20:16
 postanote             rdp-tcp#0           2  Active          .  01-Mar-21 20:16
postanote               
>postanote               
postanote
#>
```

You just need that last line. Their others are there as edification to step inot how to come to a resolution.

Again, there are other ways:

```
((query user /server:$env:COMPUTERNAME)[1] -split "\s+")[1]
((query user /server:$env:COMPUTERNAME)[1]).SubString(0,22) -replace '\W'
([regex]::Matches((query user /server:$env:COMPUTERNAME)[1],'^\s\w+').Value).TrimStart()
# Results
<#
postanote
postanote
postanote
#>
```

See also:

> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/parsing-text-with-powershell-1-3